# Appending a string inside another string using regex/ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to append parameter `?wmode=transparent` in `src` of the youtube link in iframe
e.g., for the link below:

```
<iframe frameborder=\"0\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/F4_Bq16rB2Y\" width=\"560\"></iframe>
```

I want `src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/F4_Bq16rB2Y?wmode=transparent\"` in iframe.

```
result = <iframe frameborder=\"0\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/F4_Bq16rB2Y?wmode=transparent\" width=\"560\"></iframe>
```

Using regex and/or ruby methods.

Comment: I fail to see a question here. Where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Example if str contains the whole iframe text. You can use `gsub` with grouping like so:

```
str = "<iframe ....>"
str.gsub!(/(youtube[\w\.\/]+)/, '\1?wmode=transparent')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str ='<iframe frameborder=\"0\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/F4_Bq16rB2Y\" width=\"560\"></iframe>'
puts str.gsub('\" width=', '?wmode=transparent\" width=')

#=><iframe frameborder=\"0\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/F4_Bq16rB2Y?wmode=transparent\" width=\"560\"></iframe>
```